# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - Minecraft Crashing!

Tags: java, minecraft, crash

Not sure what's happening, I'm on an HP ENVY TS15 laptop running Ubuntu Linux 12.04, I have open JDK installed, and oracle Java 7 installed...

If anyone can help me find out the problem then please reply.

I've uninstalled and re-installed Java and `.minecraft` folder!

Here is the crash readout for minecraft launcher

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----

// Shall we play a game?

Time: 7/10/14 3:02 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not init GLX
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:818)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bao.ag(SourceFile:340)
    at bao.f(SourceFile:713)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)
```

### A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

```
-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:818)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bao.ag(SourceFile:340)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bao.f(SourceFile:713)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
    Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 3.11.0-24-generic
    Java Version: 1.7.0_60, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 118320504 bytes (112 MB) / 153616384 bytes (146 MB) up to 954728448 bytes (910 MB)
    JVM Flags: 1 total; -Xmx1G
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.7.10
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

Comment: When cutting and pasting from the terminal, and easy way to format it well is to highlight the entire pasted block, and press ctrl-k

Comment: @Charles :p I never knew that! I was going through putting 4 spaces before each line

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft needs the OpenJDK 6 to work because OpenJDK 7 depreciates a lot of it's vital functions, install OpenJDK 6 [here](http://openjdk.java.net/install/)